# wordpress background for single post

Tags: wordpress

I have this plugin installed "Category Images" which basically helps me add an image for a category. it works fine.

but when i view my post, say for example a post from category "movies". can i use the background image of the category(movies) has the background image for single post of category(movies)?

**this helps me get the link of the category image.(plugin)**

```
<?php if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) echo z_taxonomy_image_url(); ?>
```

**i tried this code**

```
<style type="text/css">
body.single{
background-image:url(<?php if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) echo z_taxonomy_image_url(); ?>);
}
    </style>
```

thank you

Comment: does your body element have the .single class?

Comment: i dont seem to find .single class .. when i tried the about code it doesn't work !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to address the `body` element, the following could work:

```
<?php if ( is_single() && function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url') ): ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-image:url(<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url(); ?>);
    }
    </style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single

...you also might need to pass the image function a category ID, if you're not on a archive page:

```
<?php $category = get_the_category(); ?>
background-image:url(<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url(category[0]->term_id); ?>);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

Comment: gives me this error "syntax error, unexpected 'is_single' (T_STRING), expecting '(' in "

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant:

```
body .single{
```

instead of

```
body.single{
```

Comment: it still shows the default background image.. is it possible to get the category image has a background for the post?